# Why won't random.choice generate a random list?

Tags: python

My goal is a simple password generator. I couldn't find any references to random.choice() failing to randomly select list elements, so it must be something wrong with the structure of my code.

Here is an example of the desired output, assuming I choose '2' as my password complexity:

['X', '$', 3, 8, 'd', '+', '_', 4, 'r', '%', 'E, 2]

```
import string 
import random
def password():
    password = []
    strength = input('How strong, from 1 to 3?')
    symbol_library= ["&", '+', "#","*", "£", "$", "+", "-", "."]
    gen_integer= password.append(random.randint(0,9))
    gen_letter= password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
    gen_letter2= password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters.lower()))
    gen_symbols = password.append(random.choice(symbol_library))
    func_list= [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbols]
    func_list2 =  [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_letter2, gen_symbols]
    if strength == '1':
        while len(password)<8:
            password.append(random.choice(func_list))

        print(password)

    elif strength == '2':
        while len(password)<12:
             password.append(random.choice(func_list2))


        print(password)
```

example of an output which does vary randomly from one run to the next, but does not generate randomized list elements up until the list is the given input target length (8 and 12 respectively)

```
How strong, from 1 to 3? 2
[6, 'X', 'v', '&', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: You should edit the question instead of commenting yourself. Show an example for expected and real output as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The "append" method modifies a list in place and returns "None".

Answer (score 1):

All these are `None`, since `.append()` usually returns nothing:

```
gen_integer= password.append(random.randint(0,9))
gen_letter= password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
gen_letter2= password.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters.lower()))
gen_symbols = password.append(random.choice(symbol_library))
```

Even then, this code:

```
func_list= [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbols]
...
password.append(random.choice(func_list))
```

does not call any of the `gen_smth` functions, it just adds the function, well, pointer to the function to your password instead of letter, punctuation or a number.

Comment: I see. Can you clarify why it generates the random characters (as desired) in the same order of the func_list it is called from (not desired)? I assume it is trying to continue reporting from the func_list in the same order , but has exceeded the number of elements in that list as it continues on up to the 12-character mark and thereby fills remaining spots with None?

Answer (score 0):

```
password = []
gotcha = password.append('something')
type(gotcha)
Out[25]: NoneType
empty = random.choice([None, None, None, None])
type(empty)
Out[26]: NoneType
```

In python, when you append to a list - return type is `None`

Comment: Forgive me as I'm completely new to coding, but why is it returning the 'type' at all? I just want it to copy the randomly-selected element from one of the three randomly selected list libraries (as a string) and fill the list "password".

Comment: Ah, no worries. I was just printing out the `type` to illustrate the point. Your code isn't explicitly printing out the `type`. Basically your variables `gen_integer` etc are all `None` instead of your expected appended list

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you expect this:

```
gen_integer = password.append(random.randint(0,9))
```

to create an actual *function* that will do the operation on the right whenever you use it. That's not the way it works. Instead, it calls `password.append` to append a specific value, then stores the return value `None` into the variable `gen_integer`.

That's why you always get four values followed by four or eight `None` values, since `random.choice(func_list)` is choosing a random choice from a set of values that are all `None`.

Python *has* the capability to do this function indirection (they're called lambdas) but it may be better to simply define the functions directly and call them randomly (I've hardcoded the strength temporarily so I don't have to continuously enter it, and turned the password into a string):

```
import string
import random

def gen_integer():
    return f'{random.randint(0, 9)}'

def gen_symbol():
    return random.choice('&+#*£$+-.')

def gen_letter():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

def gen_letter2():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_letters.lower())

def make_password():
    func_list  = [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbol]
    func_list2 = [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbol, gen_letter2]

    password = ''
    strength = '2' # input('How strong (1 = weak, anything else is strong)?')
    if strength == '1':
        while len(password) < 8:
            password + random.choice(func_list)()
    else:
        while len(password) < 12:
             password += random.choice(func_list2)()

    return password

print(make_password())
```

A few sample runs show what you can get:

```
us6£3r8£a8R0
73s0l&73l9#F
0+0lg£h76&zn
6.4.3.gx+gbb
4h7Ep3-2mjp#
yCwql**8&C4z
09ll02jq£d4+
+tg75$#Dgj50
aEX8D1m+L5+j
727j#5eP59ea
```

---

If you *do* want to use lambdas, you can do so with:

```
import string
import random

def make_password():
    gen_integer = lambda: f'{random.randint(0, 9)}'
    gen_symbol  = lambda: random.choice('&+#*£$+-.')
    gen_letter  = lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    gen_letter2 = lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_letters.lower())

    func_list  = [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbol]
    func_list2 = [gen_integer, gen_letter, gen_symbol, gen_letter2]

    password = ''
    strength = '2' # input('How strong (1 = weak, anything else is strong)?')
    if strength == '1':
        while len(password) < 8:
            password + random.choice(func_list)()
    else:
        while len(password) < 12:
             password += random.choice(func_list2)()

    return password

print(make_password())
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. So where does  ```gen_integer= password.append(random.randint(0,9))```  which i then store in func_list to be called at random lose the ability to act as a function and generate random integers?

Comment: @Turner, you have to create it as a lambda (or a real function) and then ensure you call it with `random.choice(func_list)()` - note the `()` at the end. See my update.